# Isolate LAN segment from the rest of the network

Tags: networking, router, lan

[image]

Let's say I have 3 switches as seen in the image attached and each one is a different department such as sales, human resources and IT department with a different network segment such as 192.168.1.0 ; 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.0. How can I avoid the other two departments of accessing sales segment if they have to pass through the same router to go online? What about if they are connected with routers using dynamic routing?

Comment: See if your router supports VLANs

Comment: Isolate 'sales' LAN interface on the router (allow traffic from it to WAN and back, and forbid routing to another LAN ports). PS. VLANs can help, but cannot solve. Its use is possible, but is not compulsory.

Comment: If both switches and router support VLANs, physical changes are not required.

Answer (score 1):

Routers will by default forward traffic across all connected subnets. You should add a mechanism such as IP source/destination firewall rules to prevent each of your internal networks from talking to each other. The specific method of doing this would depend on your router.